# Can I transport the data of an area of a point together?

Tags: yolo

I am having a problem, in one spreadsheet I have the points read with the GPS, in the other I did the processing with YOLO v7 and got the points, however, these points have corresponding areas, and I did the joining of these two points by approximation, my question is, can I take this area in the same order that the points will be together to the final spreadsheet?

The codes I made from the junction:

```
for row in dados_yolo.iterrows():
  print(row[0], row[1]["Pixel_X"], row[1]["Pixel_Y"])

from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

df1 = dados_reais[["x", "y"]].copy()
df1.columns = ["x_real", "y_real"]

df2 = dados_yolo.copy()
df2.columns = ["x_test", "y_test"]

df1_diff = df1[['x_real', 'y_real']].values
df2_diff = df2[['x_test', 'y_test']].values
diff_matrix = cdist(df1_diff, df2_diff)

min_errors = diff_matrix.min(axis=1)

df_min_error = pd.DataFrame({
    'x_real': df1['x_real'],
    'y_real': df1['y_real'],
    'x_test': df2['x_test'].values[diff_matrix.argmin(axis=1)],
    'y_test': df2['y_test'].values[diff_matrix.argmin(axis=1)],
    'min_error': min_errors
})

df_min_error
```

I tried a few ways to fix the problem, but to no avail